# FeathersJS: Call service with express route parameters

Tags: feathersjs

I have a service defined like this:

```
app.use(`/teams/:${id}/members`, teamsMembersService);
```

Now I would like to call this service from another service. According to the documentation I can access different services using the app object. 
Like so:

```
let result = await app.service('teams').find();
```

That works well. Unfortunately this does not:

```
let result = await app.service('teams/1/members').find();
```

Because the service is undefined.

How can I call this service with route parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await app.service('teams/1/members').find();` will work if you are using the [REST client](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/rest.html#client) but not otherwise. On the server you can pass `id` in `params`:

```
app.service(`/teams/:${id}/members`).find({ id })
```

For use via Socket.io (and generally a good idea) is to add the parameter to `params.query`:

```
app.service(`/teams/:${team_id}/members`).hooks({
  before: {
    find(hook) {
      if(hook.params.team_id) {
        hook.params.query.team_id = hook.params.team_id;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Now you can do

```
app.service(`/teams/:${id}/members`).find({ query: { team_id: id } })
```